# can create glusterfs volume in docker swarm

Tags: docker, glusterfs, swarm

I have a docker swarm cluster and I'm trying to setup gluster to run in swarm. I installed gluster on all workers and tried to create a gluster volume using this command:

```
#gluster volume create dist-rep-vol gluster1:/bricks/brick1/brick gluster2:/bricks/brick2/brick
```

but I got the following error:

```
volume create: dist-rep-vol: failed: Glusterfs is not supported on brick: gluster1:/bricks/brick1/brick.
Setting extended attributes failed, reason: Operation not permitted.
```

I found online [here](http://blog.gluster.org/running-glusterfs-inside-docker-container/) that I need to set privileged to true in order to be able to set extended attributes. but I found [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24862) that this feature is not supported in swarm. is there a work around this?